# Оборотная часть картинки

Tags: transform

У меня есть две картинки. Одна видна, другую не видно. Как мне сделать чтобы при повороте видимой картинки она исчезла и появилась вторая?
-webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );

Answer (score 1):

Я бы это делал на javascript.

[Jquery](http://jquery.com/download/) +
[jQuery Image Rotate](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) +
[jQuery .hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) +
[jQuery .show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Подключаешь jQuery image rotate, создаешь callback функцию на конец поворота картинки, скрываешь картинку, и показываешь другую, также можно использовать fadeIn и fadeOut для плавного появления и исчезновения.